# Finding derivative of integral $I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+ae^x} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+ae^x} $$
How may I calculate $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1+ae^x} \ ?$$

Is there any rule for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, it's Leibniz integral rule which gives
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}I(a)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{1}{1+ae^x}\ \right)dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{-e^x dx}{(1+ae^x)^2}$$

Comment: Sorry I considered that as final result by mistake

Comment: Thanks, but I have the same problem again at the end I need to calculate the derivative of integral...

Comment: This is the derivative of the integral. The final expression is another integral

Comment: so his answer is not final right?

Comment: Sorry, misread what you said. His answer gives you the derivative in terms of an integral. You can further evaluate this integral if you wish to get a function purely in terms of $a$

Comment: For example, doing ${u=1+ae^x}$ would probably work quite well as a substitution here.

Comment: why it's easy the answer is 1/(a*(1+ae^x))

Comment: Right, but remember to plug in the bounds too i.e. ${x=1}$ and ${x=0}$

Answer (score 4):

The [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) says that this can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{da} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + ae^x} \,dx = 
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial }{\partial a} \left(\frac{1}{1 + ae^x}\right)\,dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{-e^x}{(1 + ae^x)^2}\,dx.
$$

Comment: but I have the same problem again at the end I need to calculate the derivative of integral...

Answer (score 2):

Ah, Feynman's method.  We have $$\frac{d}{da}\int_0^1\frac1{1+ae^x}\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac1{1+ae^x}\,dx=-\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{(1+ae^x)^2}\,dx.$$

This is known as [Differentiation under the Integral](https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the differentiation and integration requires justification, which is not easy. This means that it's fine to do it if you are interested in the result only, but would not be valid in an introduction to analysis course.

So let's substitute $u=ae^x$ into the integral:
$$I(a)=\int_a^{ea}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u(1+u)}$$
Using partial fraction decomposition, we have that:
$$I(a)=\int_a^{ea}\left(\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right)\mathrm{d}u=\log\left(\frac{ea}{a}\right)-\log\left(\frac{ea+1}{a+1}\right)=1+\log\left(\frac{a+1}{ea+1}\right)$$
And now we can differentiate it:
$$I'(a)=\frac{1}{a+1}-\frac{e}{ae+1}$$

Comment: you answer is different than the others here

Comment: @clark979m The $x$ in the last line was an error, it was meant to be $e$. And my answer is the same as the other answers. If you do the integrals in those answers, you will get the same result.